# how to solve this error when resizing image in pil to use it in tkinter gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am making an image viewer Tkinter GUI that opens all images in the default windows pictures folder, puts them in a list and then placing them on a label. here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


images = [Image.open(file) for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/abdel/pictures/*.png")]
image_number = 0


root = Tk()
root.title("image viewer")
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images[0].resize(250, 250))
label = Label(root, image=tkimage)
label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

def forward():
    global image_number
    global tkimage
    image_number = int(image_number)+1
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images[image_number])
    global label
    global button_forward
    global button_backward
    label.grid_forget()
    label = Label(root, image=tkimage)
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
def back():
    global image_number
    global tkimage
    image_number = int(image_number)-1
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images[image_number])
    global label
    global button_forward
    global button_backward
    label.grid_forget()
    label = Label(root, image=tkimage)
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

button_backward = Button(root, text="<<", command=back)
button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=forward)
button_forward.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_backward.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

but this error happens :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\imageviewer.py", line 12, in <module>
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images[0].resize(250, 250))
  File "C:\Users\abdel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1891, in resize
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (250). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)
```

when i write this : (.resize(250, 250)) after the tkimage object this error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\imageviewer.py", line 12, in <module>
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images[0]).resize(250, 250)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

when i use width and height parameters for the label itself, it cuts or doesn't display the whole image.

when i don't use the resizing method everything goes fine and the code works but with the real image size
is displayed which is inconvenient. how can i resize the image without these errors? and also how can i open all different formats of images not only png?

Comment: `resize(250, 250)` should be `resize((250, 250))`.

Comment: It's not `.resize(250, 250)`, but `.resize((250, 250))`. The dimensions `(width, height)` must be given as a tuple. The second parameter of [`resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) is for the resampling filter, that's why the corresponding error message.